# MVVM WPF: Get usercontrol name from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reference, viewmodel

I'm new to MVVM so please excuse my idiocy.

I have a grid containing 6 instances of a custom usercontrol.

userCtrl1,
userCtrl2,
userCtrl3,
userCtrl4,
and so on..

I created a viewModel class called 'playerInfo' and set the usercontrol's datacontext.

My question is how to reference the name in the viewmodel.

I need to get the index ( userCtrl "4" ) to reference a list in a 3rd party library I'm working with.

Sounds wierd, and I don't know if this violates the MVVM pattern.

Many thanks in advanced!

Comment: To remain within MVVM, in the Xaml you can bind the Tag to a property with two-way binding, and in your VM you can populate it incrementally.  Or alternatively use an Attached Property in your user control.  There's two alternatives...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution (if "index to reference a list" is equal to userCtrl# number and layout is not too complex):

1. Create an `ObservableCollection<PlayerInfo> Players` property in the view model.
2. Put `ItemsControl` into your view and bind to `Players`. If you want to customize layout, you can change its `ItemsPanel` template.
3. Create `DataTemplate` and set its `DataType` to `{x:Type PlayerInfo}`. Put your user control into it and bind to `{Binding}`.
4. When you need index in the view model, you can use `Players.IndexOf` method.